# Keep returning undefined from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm having some difficulties with dynamic generation of the function rootFolderId.

What I was looking for, was to dynamically assign the value of variable `rootFolder`, based on the value of the radio button chosen.But when the `.createFolder(rootFolderId,folderName)` is called, the return is undefined.

Any help please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form id="uploaderForm">
  <label for="uploaderForm">Upload multiple Files</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="applicantName" id="applicantName"
    placeholder="Your Name">
  </div>
        <div class="row">
        <p>Zgjidh lenden:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="matematike" name="gender" value="1wP_QokwCiUv1cquU-eET7g5AuFITxE9d">
  <label for="matematike">Matematike</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="dituri" name="gender" value="1I2aELHikX5f-uD6sCybQd7UevPK4WR3W">
  <label for="dituri">Dituri Natyre</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="gjuhe" name="gender" value="18xvXUYQTHGQtmkJIti-S9trqwxTYEZ5P">
  <label for="gjuhe">Gjuhe Shqipe</label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="applicantEmail" id="applicantEmail"
    placeholder="Your Email">
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles()">
  </div>
 </form>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <div id="output"></div>
 <script>
  var rootFolderId = function(){
     $('#uploaderForm input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
  var result = $(this).val();
  $('#rootFolderId').html(result);
  console.log(result);
})
}();
  var numUploads = {};
  numUploads.done = 0;
  numUploads.total = 0;
  // Upload the files into a folder in drive
  // This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
  function uploadFiles() {
 
   var allFiles = document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files;
   var applicantName = document.getElementById('applicantName').value;
   if (!applicantName) {
    window.alert('Missing applicant name!');
   }
   var applicantEmail = document.getElementById('applicantEmail').value;
   if (!applicantEmail) {
    window.alert('Missing applicant email!');
   }
   var folderName = applicantName + ' ' + applicantEmail;
            
   if (allFiles.length == 0) {
    window.alert('No file selected!');
   } else {
    numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(r) {
     // send files after the folder is created...
     for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
      // Send each file at a time
      uploadFile(allFiles[i], r.folderId);
     }
    }).createFolder(rootFolderId, folderName);
                        console.log(rootFolderId);

   }
  }

  function uploadFile(file, folderId) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
    var content = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploading '
      + file.name + '...';
    //window.alert('uploading ' + file.name + '...');    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onFileUploaded)
      .uploadFile(content, file.name, folderId);
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  function onFileUploaded(r) {
   numUploads.done++;
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'uploaded '
     + r.fileName + ' (' + numUploads.done + '/'
     + numUploads.total + ' files).';
   if (numUploads.done == numUploads.total) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'All of the '
      + numUploads.total + ' files are uploaded';
    numUploads.done = 0;
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `createFolder()` function:

```
function createFolder(parentFolderId, folderName)
{
    try {
        var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
        var folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
        var folder;

        if (folders.hasNext()) {
            folder = folders.next();
        } else {
            folder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
        }
        return { 'folderId' : folder.getId() }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return { 'error' : e.toString() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be useful to add the code for `.createFolder` method to the post?

Comment: @Teemu 

function createFolder(parentFolderId, folderName) {
 try {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  var folder;
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
   folder = folders.next();
  } else {
   folder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  return {
   'folderId' : folder.getId()
  }
 } catch (e) {
  return {
   'error' : e.toString()
  }
 }
}

Comment: I incorporated the function in the question in a suggested edit.